# How do you set the tail width of a matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch to zero?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to set the tail width of a FancyArrowPatch to zero? Setting the `tail_width` keyword of the `ArrowStyle` has not the desired effect. It is also unclear to me what the unit for this keyword actually is. I couldn't find a description in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle.html#matplotlib.patches.ArrowStyle). I assume it might be `axes points`?

MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import FancyArrowPatch


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
arrow = FancyArrowPatch(
    posA=(0, 0), posB=(1, 0), fc=None, ec='#1f77b4',
    arrowstyle='simple, head_width=10, head_length=10, tail_width=0.0',
)
ax.add_artist(arrow)
ax.set_xlim(-1, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does a tail width of zero mean you want no tail?

Comment: Yes, but setting the width to zero was the only way I could think of to accomplish this.

Comment: What about something like `arrowstyle='wedge,tail_width=40,shrink_factor=0.5'`?

Comment: Ah, not a bad idea!

Comment: I still don't undestand what the units are supposed to be though.. I don't get why this isn't mentioned anywhere

Comment: Check the difference between `tail_width=0.0` and `tail_width=10.0`. I think it's pretty obvious. Units are points, unless `mutation_scale` is changed.

Comment: Thank you! But I am not sure why your example shows that the units are obviously points. Can you explain?

Comment: I also get now why we still see a tail even though the tail width is set to zero. What we see is the contour / edge of the tail. If we set edge color to the background color, e.g. `ec='w'`, the tail disappears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you might try the wedge style instead to achieve the effect you want, e.g.

```
arrowstyle='wedge,tail_width=50,shrink_factor=0.5'
```